# Cookies not working for magento substore

Tags: magento, cookies

I have shown newsletter popup when i visit my store at first time.If i close 
popup it will never appears again until i clear cache or cookies.

This works fine in my main store.But in my sub store even though i close popup, it will show for next pages.

I have checked with different cookie variable names for both main store and sub store.

I have also checked by changing cookie path and cookie domain in magento backend.

But nothing works.Cookie not working correctly for my substore.

I have used /wholesale after main store url to access my wholesale store, not using specific domain for wholesale site.

please help me to solve my issue.

```
//set cookie
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}
```

Comment: Do you have separate theme to each store ?

Comment: Where did you place this code ?

Comment: No.I have used same theme for both stores.I have placed this code in header.phtml file

Comment: What code calls this JS?

Comment: Did you check the cookie set with i. e. Chrome Dev Tools? There is a `Resources` tab, inside on the left the is a "Cookies" section. In that section you can see your cookies for your substore - Please make sure you set the cookie for the right domain, right path. Please post an image of that so we can check as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by setting cookie path specific for sub store.

```
//set cookie
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    if(url.indexOf('wholesale') > -1) {
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires+";path=/wholesale";
    } else {
     document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }
}
```